# Create Docker image for deb packages

Tags: docker, debian, dockerfile, deb

I have a deb packages created, I need to set up one docker image for these files.

.buildinfo
.changes
.deb
.ddeb

Any pointers or documentation to create a Docker image. I have searched for same in google and found only how to create deb packages using docker containers.

Comment: Are you trying to package up a .deb package? Bit confused on what you actually need.

Comment: Yes , I have to create an image for those packages . once the container is created the packages should be in there.

Comment: @Bobby are you able to create docker image containing debian packages? Please post the solution.